# How to bridge a virtual interface inside docker container?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, docker

Let me re-organised the question.
I have used a similar docker-compose yaml file as below.

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - frontend
 
networks:
  frontend:
     driver: bridge
     ipam:
       config:
         - subnet: 172.38.3.0/24
```

A network interface `eth0` will be created automatically inside the dock container APP. I can connect to the network of the host through `eth0`.

Now I want to create other virtual network interfaces inside the docker container APP, such as `veth1`, `veth2`.
I want to let the packets through `veth1`/`veth2` can access the host network. Like the below,

```bsh
ping -I veth1 host-network-ip
```

by the way, I have tried to define one more network in the yaml and attached to docker container APP. but unfortunately, the network interface name `eth1` inside docker container could not be customized. I need to specify the network interface name.

Is it possible to let it work? if yes, can you please help to explain how to do? Thank you very much!

Comment: There's LOTS of `iptables` stuff inside the containers, so even if you add veth pairs, I'd doubt it would work well. Instead, consider using [custom networks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks) in your docker compose file. (You didn't describe your actual use case, see [XY questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but chances your original problem X can be solved through this are high).

Comment: @dirkt   Thank you very much for your reply. I have updated my question. Hope it's more clear now. I have tried to define one more network in docker-compose yaml, but it could not specify the network interface name inside docker container.

Comment: You still have not explained **why** you want different network interfaces, and why you want to access the host network. What is your **use case**? Is something on the host running you want to access? Do you want extra filtering on the network interfaces? What do you hope to gain from doing it this way, instead of following the docker model and exposing ports for services to the outside world, and letting services within containers communicate with each other?